# How can I automate resque workers to update their code when I push my app to heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, resque

**The problem is:**

When I make changes on the code performed by the workers, the running workers on heroku still executes with the previous after I pushed a new code.

Then I have to manually stop and start again resque. But its wrong, I guess, because the worker could be performing some job and must have to wait it until fininhes to be unregistered.

This is my **resque.rake**

```
require 'resque'
require "resque/tasks"

task "resque:setup" => :environment do
  ENV['QUEUE'] = '*' if ENV['QUEUE'].blank?

  Resque::Worker.all.each {|w| w.unregister_worker}
  Resque.after_fork do |job| 
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end
end

task "resque:clean_workers" => :environment do
  Resque::Worker.all.each {|w| w.unregister_worker}
end

desc "Alias for resque:work (To run workers on Heroku)"
task "jobs:work" => "resque:work"

Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/jobs/*.rb"].each { |file| require file }
```

I would like to know if when I push my app to heroku, the worker could be updated with the new code. How could it be done?

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you sure the previous workers are still running? What do your Heroku logs look like after a push? What about `heroku ps`?

Comment: After deploy it shows "0 of 1 Workers", but its dirty. It's suposed to heroku do it itself? I'm running resque with `heroku run:detached bundle exec rake resque:work QUEUE=*`. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku restarts all your processes on deploy as a platform feature -- except for one-off processes spawned via `heroku run`.

Add the worker process type to your [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile):

```
worker: bundle exec rake resque:work QUEUE=*
```

Push, and then tell Heroku to run your worker:

```
$ heroku ps:scale worker=1
```

Heroku will now ensure that you have a single `worker` dyno running at all times. It'll restart it automatically when your app restarts (e.g. after a push, a `heroku restart`, a [rollback](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/releases#rollback)), or if your worker dies somehow, or if the host it's on fails. Heroku will even gracefully shut down and restart your worker process on a new host every day or so just for good measure, purging temp files, putting a cap on any memory leaks, and rebalancing load around the dyno grid.

This is the behavior you want if you're running background jobs 24x7 in production.

Comment: Thanks! I will put inside the procfile a worker: `worker: bundle exec rake worker:all`. That should call the resque rake task and my others sqs poll tasks